# Idiomatic clojure conditionally calling a function

Tags: clojure, idioms

I have a clojure function that needs to push information into a map if a particular condition is true, using that map as a parameter for another function.

I have the following, but it feels clumsy with the repeated calls to the bar function.

```
(defn foo ([opts]

  (if (= true (something))       
    (bar (into opts {:a b}))
    (bar opts)))

(def bar [opts])
```

So if (something) is true, we push extra options into the opts parameter before calling the bar function, otherwise we just pass it through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing is that `(= true (something))` can be replaced simply by `(something)` with no issues (unless you are actually trying to differentiate between a return value of `true` and a return value of, say, `1`).  If the options for the return value are `true` and `false`, `(something)` by itself will work fine.  You can also use merge instead of into, which might be slightly clearer.

You could try

```
(bar (if (something)
       (merge opts {:a b})
       opts))
```

This would work as well, though it involves calling `merge` unnecessarily when `(something)` is false, though with `nil` for the second argument, `merge` should return very quickly.

```
(bar (merge opts
            (when (something)
              {:a b})))
```

Comment: Since `(into {} nil) => {}`, you could do `(bar (into opts (when (something) {:a b})))`. It's also possible to use `merge` instead of `into`.

Answer (score 2):

retief's answer is all right. It should be noted that `if` is an expression in Clojure instead of just a conditional construct. Therefore, it has a return value and you can use the return value as a parameter to functions:

```
(bar (if (something)       
        (into opts {:a b})
         opts))
```

You can think of it as the ternary operator in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since Clojure 1.5 this can be written

```
(cond-> opts (something) (merge {:a b}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the conditional code into function(s). Something  like:

```
(defn addAIfSomethig [opt] (if (something) (into opts {:a "A"}) opt) )
(defn addBIfSomethig [opt] (if (something) (into opts {:b "B"}) opt) )
```

Then in your function where you need to modify the opt before calling bar use function composition.

```
(defn foo [opt]
    (let [modifiers (comp addAIfSomethig addBIfSomethig)]
      (bar (modifiers opt))
    ))
```

Comment: I really appreciate the down vote, but adding the reason as comment would make it awsome

Comment: It is not idiomatic to use `camelCase` function names in Clojure. You can write `(defn <*_-!magicalFruit!-_*> [] (+ 1 1))`, but if you don't want your code to stick out like a sore thumb stick with `foo-bar`, `foo-bar?`, `foo-bar!`, and (maybe) `foo->bar` when it comes to function definitions unless there's a good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the clojure (and general lisp) style